# iostream being ignored even when stafx.h still present?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

So i have to be missing something here but every time i try to build my code it throws a handful of errors, mostly stating "#include : skipped when looking for precompiled header and just entirely ignoring anything i have in the #include

my header file only includes the iostream and my source file include

```
#include <iostream>
#include<ctime>
#include "HeaderFiles.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
```

my output when im trying to build it is:

1>c:\users\syoun\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project2\project2.cpp(1): warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use

1>  c:\users\syoun\onedrive\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\project2\project2.cpp(1): note: Add directive to 'stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header

Im just lost and frustrated at this point because i have no clue what caused this. anyone that could help please do.

Comment: When using precompiled headers `#include "stdafx.h"` must be the 1st include in your *.cpp files.

Comment: That did it, thank you, saved me some continued frustration.